# How to prevent the TokenMismatchException reliably during Ajax calls in Laravel?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I know there have been many questions asked before about handling the CSRF token on Ajax calls in Laravel. The Laravel docs **[specify a way](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-x-csrf-token)** to pass the csrf_token value on any Ajax request like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
});
```

and **this is exactly what I'm doing** in my app.

However, there are still plenty of cases when the `TokenMismatchException` gets thrown and logged on the server. I think one reason for this is the following:

1. User loads a page and leaves the page open
2. Laravel session expires
3. The user gets back to the PC and triggers an Ajax call (e.g. by clicking on a button)
4. The Ajax call gathers the `csrf-token` value from the meta tag

Now, the `csrf-token` value passed wth the call is, of course, wrong now, as Laravel session doesn't exist and needs to be regenerated.

Laravel docs also **[suggests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-x-xsrf-token)** using the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie. However, the cookie has - obviously - the same expiration date as the `laravel_session` cookie, which won't help me either.

Notice that the user doesn't necessarily have to be authenticated to generate Ajax calls, they can be fired by guest users, and all are checked against cross-site request forgery.

**Is there a way to get around this and prevent the `TokenMismatchException` in situations like I described above?**

Sidenote:

The case I described is probably not the only one. The exception's been thrown and logged 36 times in the past 24 hours, and I'm sure those occurrences cannot all be linked the same issue, especially as these are various Ajax calls - both GET and POST.

Answer (score 0):

Try another way to pass the token using ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/your/url',

    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
    },

    success: function (data) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

Or, you have the option to exclude URIs From CSRF Protection:

> Typically, you should place these kinds of routes outside of the web middleware group that the RouteServiceProvider applies to all routes in the routes/web.php file. However, you may also exclude the routes by adding their URIs to the $except property of the VerifyCsrfToken middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'stripe/*',
    ];
}
```

[Source/docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris)

Answer (score 0):

Include the following in the page in which you are adding ajax code.

```
<input type="hidden" id="token" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token();?>" />

var token = $('#token').val();
$.ajax({
       url: "your-url",
       method: "POST",
       data: {
         _token : token,
         required_fields: your-fields
       },
       success: function(result) {
         if(result.success == true) {
          // required action upon success
         }
       }
 });
```

});

Added an id="token" field to the hidden input type & obtained that value using jquery and passed it in ajax request data as _token field.This can get the thing corrected without any TokenMismatchException errors while using ajax requests.